# How to change line height for small text with CSS? There seems to be a limit to how small line-height can be

Tags: html, css

For example, in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/g5sa5/), how do I get rid of the spacing between the lines of text (on top of the images)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your `line-height` on `.box_desc`. I also adjusted your `top` value to compensate:

```
.box_desc {
     position: absolute;
     top: 14px;
     line-height: 10px;
 }
```

You should tweak the `line-height`/`top` values to perfection.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/XhZMv/

Comment: Wow, thanks! So how'd you know for that to work? Why will it work if you apply the line-height to `.box_desc` but not when you apply the line-height to `.box_desc_title`?

Comment: That's how it works. For a minimal test case, see: http://jsfiddle.net/cjusp/ - and I think I've found the relevant quotes in the spec, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height - compare the two sentences there that start with `"On a block container element"` vs `"On a non-replaced inline element"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `font-size:0; line-height:0;` also fixed width and height.

Comment: lol, that makes the text disappear. i think its a limitation by the browser... it seems that any text 12px and below is limited to a line height that is higher than the text's normal line-height and so you will always have space.

Comment: nevermind, seems thirtydot found a solution in with his answer!